# Strange error: The given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

Here is my code:

```
public Dictionary<int, CharacterActionBarSpells> AllcharacterActionBarSpells = new Dictionary<int, CharacterActionBarSpells>();

private void Test(){
    int lastInsertID = Convert.ToInt32(cmdInsert.LastInsertedId); 
    foreach(var item in AllcharacterActionBarSpells)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("KEY:" + item.Key + " ID: " + item.Value.id + " spell " + item.Value.spell + " slot: " + item.Value.spell);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Last inserted id: " + lastInsertID);
    AllcharacterActionBarSpells.Add(lastInsertID, new CharacterActionBarSpells()
    {
        id = lastInsertID,
        character_id = Convert.ToInt32(abcSpells["character_id"]),
        spell = Convert.ToInt32(abcSpells["spell"]),
        actionbar_group = Convert.ToInt32(abcSpells["actionbar_group"]),
        slot = Convert.ToInt32(abcSpells["new_slot"])
    });
 }
```

Here is the console output:

```
KEY:1 ID: 1 spell 1 slot: 1
KEY:2 ID: 2 spell 2 slot: 2
KEY:3 ID: 3 spell 3 slot: 3
KEY:4 ID: 4 spell 4 slot: 4
KEY:19 ID: 19 spell 2 slot: 2
KEY:20 ID: 20 spell 3 slot: 3
KEY:21 ID: 21 spell 3 slot: 3
Last inserted id: 22
```

As you can see `AllcharacterActionBarSpells.Add(lastInsertID,` I have total of seven records. The last one with key of `21`. So after that I'm trying to add a new record to the dictionary but I receive the following error:

```
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: 'The given key was not present in the dictionary.'
```

Basically `lastInsertID` is the last inserted ID after the MySQL insert. I'm sure `AllcharacterActionBarSpells` is not empty if it is even important. I think there is no need for the dictionary to be empty in order to put data in it, am I correct?

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I add a new record to the dictionary and why am I receiving this error?

Comment: What is `abcSpells`? What line is throwing the exception?

Comment: please check if abcspells has values for all 4 keys : character_id, spell, actionbar_group, new_slot

Comment: 4 of them have data: `"characterId":"1","old_slot":"0","new_slot":"7","spell":"2","actionbar_group":"1"` This is the data of `abcSpells`

Comment: @AlexWiese this line is throwing the exception: `                AllcharacterActionBarSpells.Add(lastInsertID, new CharacterActionBarSpells()
`

Comment: Put the code and data causing the error [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49481584/edit). Show where the error occurs [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49481584/edit). It does no good to add it to comments.

Comment: Something in `abcSpells` is not there, `abcSpells` doesn't have anything to do with the `AllcharacterActionBarSpells`, so the code you posted doesn't have that error. The dictionary throwing the error though is `abcSpells`, not the other one.

Comment: try separating the creation of CharacterActionBarSpells instance and addition to dictionary as 2 separate actions.. i.e. create the instance of CharacterActionBarSpells first and store it in a variable. In the next line, add the newly created instance to the dictionary. This will help you to zero-in on the error.

Comment: @RonBeyer you were right. I found the mistake thank you.

Comment: You say the dictionary has "characterId" but in the code you try to access with key "character_id"...

Comment: @Chris yes this was the problem. Thank you.